# How to make a textbox only accept numbers from 0-10 and only .5 from decimal part?

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-input

I have a text box where users should only enter between 0-10 and decimal part allowed is .5 
So one can enter 0 or .5 or 1.5 or 4 etc nothing other.
Here I can add all numbers:

```
<script>
  function handleChange(input) {
    if (input.value < 0) input.value = 0;
    if (input.value > 10) input.value = 10;
  }
</script>
<input type="text" onchange="handleChange(this);" />
```

I need to alert on wrong entry and to reset that text box.

Comment: you can also do this in html5 <input type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.5" required="">

Comment: Another option would be to just have a `pattern` attribute that matches 0 to 10, no Javascript required, though that wouldn't be able to reset the box, only tell the user that the input was invalid

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya how to prevent user from entering vaues

Comment: @qww like what kind of values you want to prevent from being entered

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya anything other than allowed... so that  i can replace number type to text and prevent from 0 to 10 with step .5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending @Vishnu Badhoriya's comment, we could also do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<input id="number" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.5" onchange="roundHalf(this.value)">
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
function roundHalf(num) {
  if (num > 10) {
    $('#number').val(10);
  } else if (num < 0) {
    $('#number').val(0);
  } else {
    $('#number').val(Math.round(num*2)/2);
  }
}
```

You could take a non-jQuery approach as well, but I just chose to do so because of ease of demonstration. This will make sure that the user won't be able to enter his own values.

Check out the CodePen here to see it in action:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBoJGB

EDIT: Forgot to implement the other constraint, for 0 <= num <= 10. Added that to the code snippet.

Comment: but i need to block all values above 10 and below 0

Comment: yes the above min and max attributes will prevent from begin entered < 0 AND  > 10

Comment: Okay, I believe he wants the manual entry of higher numbers also to be restricted. I did forget that constraint. That should be simple. You just need to add the if condition you've implemented in your question inside the roundHalf() function and if the value is above 10, then change the input's value to 10.